# Central Administration not opening after installing patch

Tags: sharepoint-server

Recently, I installed the October 2017 cumulative update in SharePoint 2016 on-premises farm. But after completing the patching process successfully, Central Administration site is inaccessible and gives the error "This page can't be displayed" when opened on Distributed Cache server in the farm. On other servers in the farm, Central Administration can be easily accessed. I checked the services that needs to be up and running and everything seems to be fine. Please suggest.

Comment: How many servers in farm? Check the iis on the central admin server if anything missing? Web app stopped or missing bindings?

Comment: also try to re-run the config wizard once again after the patch installation

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down this issue, check the following:

1. Run the Products Configuration Wizard in this server and check again.
2. Check the network settings, make sure the server can ping the SharePoint Server.
3. Check if other SharePoint sites can open in this server.
4. Use another browser to open the CA site.
5. Check the ULS log to find more error message.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1. I ran the configuration wizard multiple times which gets completed successfully, but still the issue persists. 2. Checked the network settings and can ping the SharePoint server from the affected server successfully. 3. SharePoint sites are accessible inside the server but not the Central Administration site. 4. Tried Firefox but the issue still persists. 5. Checked ULS logs but not able to find the relevant reason.